# Can i use ViewModelProvider and Observe in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I user MVVM and RecyclerView in this app so the recycle view show the list perfectly but when i add the view model to adapter i get an error in the logcat

> Your activity is not yet attached to the Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.

i am new in this MVVM and i know is this possible or is any other way to do this

this is my adapter class with the viewHolder

```
class KeefAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<KeefViewHolder>() {
    var dataOfAllKeef = listOf<String>()

    init {
        dataOfAllKeef = arrayListOf("Marijuwana" , "Bango" , "Weed" , "Hash")
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KeefViewHolder {
        lateinit var binding: KeefSingleItemBinding

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context) , R.layout.keef_single_item , parent , false)
        val viewModel:OrderYourKeefViewModel = ViewModelProvider(OrderYourKeef()).get(OrderYourKeefViewModel::class.java)
        binding.orderViewModelWithSingle = viewModel
        viewModel.count.observe(OrderYourKeef(), Observer { newCountOfHash->
            binding.root.theCountOfHash.text = newCountOfHash.toString()
        })

        return KeefViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataOfAllKeef.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KeefViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataOfAllKeef[position]
        holder.keefName.text = item

        if (item.equals("Marijuwana")) {
            holder.keefImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.marijuana)
        } else if (item.equals("Bango")) {
            holder.keefImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bango)
        } else if (item.equals("Weed")) {
            holder.keefImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.weed)
        } else if (item.equals("Hash")) {
            holder.keefImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.hashesh)
        }
    }
}

class KeefViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var keefName:TextView = itemView.keefName
    var keefImage: ImageView = itemView.keefImage
    var increase: Button = itemView.increaseTheCount
    var decrease: Button = itemView.minusTheCount
    var theCountOfKeef: TextView = itemView.theCountOfHash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the correct way to implement the MVVM pattern.

You have to call the `viewModel = ViewModelProviders` in your Activity. And after fetching the list items, pass it to your adapter and call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
updateListItems(newListItems: List<YourItem>) {
    currentItems = newListItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

[Read more about it here](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-with-kotlin-android-architecture-components-dagger-2-retrofit-and-rxandroid-1a4ebb38c699)

Answer (score 0):

Adapter seems to be designed to be used rather *passively* than actively.

In OP's code, he would observe and get `newCountOfHash` in `onCreateViewHolder` to set it to `binding.root.theCountOfHash.text`. So this is a case that Adapter would *actively* seek and grab a value.

To avoid this 'active' Adapter, we should define Adapter behaving passively. Locally define `countOfHash` as Adapter's field value. The Adapter shouldn't mind `countOfHash` is LiveData or not. It just looks the field value.

```
class KeefAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<KeefViewHolder>() {
    var countOfHash

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KeefViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // You should not do this in onCreateViewHolder
        // because that is done only once on creation time.
        // (not invoked later again)
        binding.root.theCountOfHash.text = countOfHash
    }
}
```

Then outside of the Adapter, from Activity or Fragment that holds the Adapter, you may update `Adapter.countOfHash` with an Observer:

```
val viewModel:OrderYourKeefViewModel
    = ViewModelProvider(OrderYourKeef()).get(OrderYourKeefViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.count.observe(OrderYourKeef(), Observer { newCountOfHash ->
    Adapter.countOfHash = newCountOfHash.toString()
})
```

(Note: I'm not using Kotlin actively, there may be some syntax mistakes)